# CSS Specificity Counter

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, css-specificity

So the CSS specificity [rules](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) dictate that ids are the most powerful, then classes, then tag names and then *.

So `#id` > `.class` > `div` > `*`.

What I'm trying to do is get a 'rating' for each if I provide a string of CSS selectors.

Say I have a Specificity array = `[#id, .class, tagname]`

`span` should return `[0, 0, 1]`

`body p` should return `[0, 0, 2]`

`.red .orange` should return `[0, 2, 0]`

`menu .item #checkout.active` should return `[1, 2, 1]`

I've tried this code, but something is definitely off:

```
function compare(a) {
    const comparisonOperators = ["#", ".", " "];
    const aRating = [];

    for (let x = 0; x < comparisonOperators.length; x++) {
        aRating[x] = a.includes(comparisonOperators[x])
            ? a.split(comparisonOperators[x]).filter((x) => x).length
            : 0;
    }

    console.log(aRating);
}

compare("menu .item #checkout.active");
// returns [2,3,3]
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: It is counting accurately.  When you split on '#'  you have two elements 'menu .item ' and 'checkout.active'    When you split on '.' you have three elements  'menu ',  'item @checkout', and 'active'   And when you split on " " you also have three elements "menu", ".item", and "#checkout.active"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken a different approach than yours to solve this.

```
function compare(a) {
    var items = a.split([' ']);
    var aRating = [0,0,0];
    items.forEach(function(i) {
        //case 1
        if(i.split('#').length > 1) {
            aRating[0] = aRating[0] + (i.split('#').length - 1)
        }
        //case 2
        if(i.split('.').length > 1) {
            aRating[1] = aRating[1] + (i.split('.').length - 1)
        }
        //case 3
        if(!i.startsWith('#') && !i.startsWith('.')) { 
            aRating[2] = aRating[2] + 1
        }
        
    });
    console.log(aRating);
}
```

Initially, I'm splitting the string based on whitespace. This gives the total number of elements to check for. I'm then looping over each item in that array to determine and count the number of selectors.

In case 1, if an item contains an `ID` then its length will be greater than 1. For example, `#myId`. If I split this based on `#` then I'll get 2 items in an array. I'm using this to determine if it contains an `ID` or not. In this case, it's true so I increment the `aRating` array by 1. If it is not an `ID` then its length will always be 1 because it cannot be split.

The same logic is applied to case 2 for css `class`.

Case 3 is slightly different. If a string does not start with `#` or a '.', then it must be a tagname.